# Integral with respect to Brownian motion with deterministic functions (sinus, cosinus) as an integrands

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I have a question concerning the following problem:

> Let $B^{(1)}$ and $B^{(2)}$ denote two independent Brownian motions. Let $$W_t^{(1)} = \int_0^t \sin(s)dB^{(1)}_s + \int_0^t \cos(s)dB^{(2)}_s$$and let
> $$W_t^{(2)} = \int_0^t \cos(s)dB^{(1)}_s - \int_0^t \sin(s)dB^{(2)}_s.\\ $$
> Show that $W_t^{(1)}$ and $W_t^{(2)}$ define two independent Brownian Motions.

I tried using Ito's formula for $f_1(x,t) = x\sin(t)$ and $f_2(x,t) = x\cos(t)$, but I don't really see where it is going. And for the independence I don't have an idea yet.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you know Levy's characterization of Brownian Motion?

Comment: Hint: what is $\langle W^{(i)},W^{(j)}\rangle_t$ ?

Comment: Levy Characterization seems perfect. But does it also give us independence? Also: Can we just say that that for example W^(1) is a martingale? It is the sum of two martingales but with respect to different filtrations, or am I wrong?

Comment: The cross variation of W^(1) and W^(2) is 0, right? I got 4 integrals and two of them had d0 in the end of the integral and the other two cancelled each other. But I am not sure if I could compute the cross-variation like that, but it seems so. So, considering the fact that the quadr. variation of both W^(1) and W^(2) is t |-> t, we can use the Levy Characterization Theorem.